# Could the word "Gobbledygook" be considered gobbledygook itself?

Tags: vocabulary

Words which are gobbledygook are words which are large, not meaningful, not comprehensible to a large portion of the target audience, or a combination of these. Suppose I was speaking to a crowd of people, most of which not understanding what the word meant, and mentioned gobbledygook. Considering the word "gobbledygook" is a large word that may seem to be gibberish and is not known by my target audience, would it be considered gobbledygook itself?

Comment: If **gobbledygook** is *[onomatopoeic](https://www.lexico.com/definition/onomatopoeic) (words like ‘bang’ and ‘coo’)* then yes.

Comment: From my research it seems to be imitating a turkey's gobble, so I believe it is onomatopoeia

Comment: If you have already lost your audience, then you might as well go for it. There may be one or two who cheer :)

Comment: *Gobbledygook* is only gobbledygook to people who don't know what it means … and using that word to describe it to those people would be a kind of meta statement.

Comment: But isn't "onomatopoeic" gobbledygook?

Comment: @HotLicks: Not if you look it up, it isn't. ;) On a more serious note, years ago my wife was trying to socialize with a German woman who spoke little to no English. My wife wanted to say "Champagne," but couldn't think of the term and instead said "bubbly wine," which made the German lady laugh. "Bubbly wine" was likely gobbledygook to her, but with enough onomatopoeic quality to somehow make sense.

Comment: Sometimes 'gobbledygook' is a word used by uneducated (or deliberately "know-nothing") people when they encounter a word they have not heard before.